# load GMSMapView in uitableviewcell in background thread

Tags: objective-c, background-thread, gmsmapview

I want to load the gmsmapview in the view inside the cell.
Below code works proper. But it tableview scroll is not smoth.
Because of the everytime the mapview get load and it take time.
Is there any other option to load mapview in background thread

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 CellMap *cell=[tableView 



                                                  //do the fetching of data here(Don't do any UI Updates)
                                                  GMSMapView *mapView_;

                                                  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:kGoogleKey];
                                                  // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
                                                  // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
                                                  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86 longitude:151.20
                                                                                                               zoom:6];
                                                  mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
                                                  mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;

                                                  // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
                                                  GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
                                                  marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(modelitemobj.latitude,modelitemobj.longitude);
                                                  marker.title = modelitemobj.strCity;
                                                  //marker.snippet = @"Australia";
                                                  marker.map = mapView_;
                                                  mapView_.frame=cell.mapView.frame;
                                                  [cell.mapView addSubview:mapView_];



return cell;
}
```

Please help me

Comment: did you find any solution?